# Help. Java-script phone number validation for blackberry

Tags: javascript, validation, blackberry, cookies

Hi I am trying to validate a phone number for a cookie via java-script. The prompt works great but the validation does not. This is for a blackberry webworks app.

I read other posts but I am missing something

```
            function checkCookie()
            {
               var username=getCookie("username");
               if (username!=null && username!="")
               {
                //alert("Your Phone Number is " + username);
               }
               else 
               {
                  username=prompt("When asked you can receive texted coupons. Please enter your Phone Number:","");
                  if (username!=null && username!="")
                  {                      
                   function validatePhone(username)
                   {
                     if (field.match(/^\d{10}/)) {
                     setCookie("username",username,365);
                     return true;
                   } 
                   alert("wrong");
                   return false;
                 }
               }                        
            }
          }
```

Comment: Do **all** phone numbers have 10 digits? Mine doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see an actual call to the validatePhone function. You've defined it, but never call it.

Try this instead:

```
function validatePhone(sInput) {
    return /^\d{10}$/.test(sInput);
}

function checkCookie() {
    var username=getCookie("username");
    if(username!=null && username!="") {
        // alert("Your Phone Number is " + username);
    } else {
        username=prompt("When asked you can receive texted coupons. Please enter your Phone Number:","");
        if(username!=null && username!="") {
            var bValid = validatePhone(username);
            if(bValid) {
                setCookie("username",username,365);
                return true;
            } else {
                alert('wrong');
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: I switched the validation function to use RegExp.test instead of String.match.

Comment: Works great.  I also researched RegExp. I didn't know what that was at first. I am still learning. Thank you so much.

Comment: Regular Expressions are the best thing since sliced bread. Learn to love them. :-)